# Custom Workflows in plone 4

Tags: comments, plone

In our Plone site we have people making comments on documents. The person who wrote the document will need to respond to the commentor. I created a group for writers and gave them the Reviewer role. The problem I have is that all the writers in the group can see each others comments and can approve or delete each others comments. I need to make it possible for the writers to only see their comments. Would I do this with workflows? or is there an easier way?

Comment: I'd like to help you, but it seems I'm too dumb, to get comments working in a P-4.3.3: After enabling commenting on a document, no 'Add comment'-button shows up. Am I missing something, respectively can you tell me which Plone-version you are using?

Comment: Ah ok, one also needs to enable commenting globally in the comments-controlpanel (@@discussion-settings), wasn't obvious/not mentioned in the README.

Answer (score 2):

To a zeroth approximation, I'd give the permission `Review comments` to the `Owner` (pseudo-)role in the ZMI Security tab, which will only them give permission to approve/delete comments. (This permission is not managed by any of the standard workflows.) 
This would also lead to pending comments not being visible to others; I'm not confident Plone's default commenting mechanism is equipped to closely control visibility of comments once they're approved, though.

Comment: I agree, that for global solution, simply assigning `Review comments` to `Owner` would suffice, just like to add, that the OP should grant the Contributor-role to the users, instead of Reviewer's and also needs to enable "Enable comment moderation" in the comments-controlpanel via @@discussion-settings. Feel free to complement your answer with these additions.